# Command 'yarn build' fails on Windows 10 for REACT_APP_RELEASE variable

Tags: node.js, react-native, build, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

Inside `package.json` the `build` script is something like:

```
"build": "REACT_APP_RELEASE=$npm_package_version REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF=$COMMIT_REF react-scripts build && echo $COMMIT_REF >> build/version.txt",
```

When I run the command `yarn build` I get following error:

```
'REACT_APP_RELEASE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step 1

Install the `cross-env` module.

```
npm install cross-env
```

or

```
yarn add cross-env
```

#### Step 2

Add `cross-env` before `REACT_APP_RELEASE` variable in the `build` script. If `REACT_APP_RELEASE` variable is in the middle of your build script you have to always add `cross-env` just before the `REACT_APP_RELEASE` variable.

Full command:

```
"build": "cross-env REACT_APP_RELEASE=$npm_package_version REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF=$COMMIT_REF react-scripts build && echo $COMMIT_REF >> build/version.txt",
```